# Asp.net core SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, join

```
 var value = from p in _context.Projects
                           join s in _context.Clients on p.ClientId equals s.Id
                           select new { Client = s };
```

i want to not equals i tried <> and != but not wrok.
how to do that ?

I have been trying to retrieve data from the client model that does not exist in the project model. To be more specific, I have the client file in the project model.
So, I want to retrieve all records that do not exist in the project_client_Fk column.

Comment: use .Expect() instead of not equals

Comment: var value = from p in _context.Projects
                           join s in _context.Clients on p.ClientId equals s.Id
                           where p.ClientId == id
                           select new { Client = s };

Comment: Could you please share your `Projects` and `Clients` model details along with any sample data if you have?

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587) As instructed in [ask], can you please describe your problem **_before_** showing code?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to retrieve all records that do not exist in the
> project_client_Fk column.

Let's assume, you have following class:

**Class:**

```
public class Client
    {
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Technology { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Sample Data:**

```
var clientList = new List<Client>()
 {
   new Client(){ ClientId =101,Name = "Client-A",Address = "CAN-Ontaria"},
   new Client(){ ClientId =102,Name = "Client-B",Address = "CAN-Alberta"},
   new Client(){ ClientId =103,Name = "Client-C",Address = "US-Silicon Valley"},
    
 };
    
var projectList = new List<Project>()
  {
   new Project(){ ProjectId =301,Name = "Pro-A",Technology = "C#",ClientId =101},
   new Project(){ ProjectId =302,Name = "Pro-B",Technology = "Asp.net core",ClientId =101 },
   new Project(){ ProjectId =303,Name = "Pro-C",Technology = "Web API",ClientId =102},
    
  };
```

**Note:** We can see `ClientId =103` has no project. Or between `clientList` and `projectList` unmatched or non-existent data is `ClientId =103`. So we would be writing a query which will return us, unmatched data between the two table.

**Way:1**

We can use [`ExceptBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-7.0) to distinguish non-matched item from the two table or list as following:

```
    List<Client> unmatchedResult = clientList
   .ExceptBy(projectList.Select(nonExist => nonExist.ClientId), nonExist => nonExist.ClientId)
   .ToList();
```

**Way:2**

Using normal Linq (following SQL join concept) query we even can achive that.

```
var findUnmatched = from client in clientList
                    where !(from project in projectList select project.ClientId)
                   .Contains(client.ClientId)
                    select client;
```

**Note:** In your scenario, you would replace `_context.Projects` and `_context.Clients`

**Output:**

[image]